# Excel Chart to Swap x and y axis

Tags: excel, swap, excel-charts

i have a population [Pyramid which is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJyjp.jpg), is there a way to swap x and y axis without change chart type? After swap, the chart will be similar to [the one here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LCUN.jpg), but with the age on the left and percentage at the bottom. i am using excel 2016.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible without changing the chart type. Why do you NOT want to change the chart type? It's just a few clicks.

The first image has a **column** chart with vertical columns. The second image shows the same chart flipped on its side. Excel has the vertical column chart and also the horizontal bar chart, which is a column chart flipped on its side.

If you don't want to change the chart type, take a screenshot of the chart and rotate it sideways. But if you want a properly formatted chart you will need to change the chart type to a **horizontal bar** chart instead of a vertical column chart.